# Why (and how) does the order of an Enum influence the ToString value?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, enums

I have problems with the "order" of the values of an enum. It's a little difficult to explain, that's why I wrote up some code:

```
class Program
{
    public enum EnumA
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = One,
        Three = Two,
        Four = 4
    }

    public enum EnumB
    {
        One = 1,
        Two = One,
        Four = 4,
        Three = Two
    }

    public enum EnumC
    {
        Two = One,
        Three = Two,
        Four = 4,
        One = 1
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enum A:");
        Console.WriteLine(EnumA.One);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumA.Two);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumA.Three);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumA.Four);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enum B:");
        Console.WriteLine(EnumB.One);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumB.Two);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumB.Three);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumB.Four);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enum C:");
        Console.WriteLine(EnumC.One);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumC.Two);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumC.Three);
        Console.WriteLine(EnumC.Four);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

Enum A:
Two
Two
Two
Four

Enum B:
Three
Three
Three
Four

Enum C:
One
One
One
Four

My question is: WHY!? I can't find the logic to the output. Most of the time there is some logic to be found, so I hope you guys can shine some light on this issue.

I used VS2010 / .Net 4.0 to compile and run the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behaviour is specified to be "undefined" (I thought I'd spotted a pattern just now, but apparently not.) The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx) explicitly calls this out:

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

Either make your enum values distinct, or explicitly create a map from value to desired name.

Comment: Hey Jon, I thought the same, but... in case of EnumA it should be Three and not Two. Even if I change the value Three = One, the EnumA.Three.ToString() remains "Two".

Comment: I see... how weird! I encountered the problem using an enum with file formats and stuff like that. Still... it's weird, isn't it?

Comment: @Kees: I don't think it's particularly weird - it's like hash tables not being ordered. (Indeed, it may be based on exactly that :)

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker It would be better if synonyms like the above were disallowed completely, but of course that's to late to change now (would be an extremely breaking change). Also note that `Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumA))` returns an array of length 4, not 2, in this case. Many people are confused by that. With Linq, use `((EnumA[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumA))).Distinct()` to fix that.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Better still would be if one could designate some enum values as being "canonical" and others as "aliases"; canonical values could be validated for uniqueness, while `ToString` would ignore aliases.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to observe, if you decompile the IL, is that the calls to `WriteLine` all look remarkably similar:

```
    L_000c: ldc.i4.1 
    L_000d: box ConsoleApplication2.Program/EnumA
    L_0012: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_0017: nop 
    L_0018: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0019: box ConsoleApplication2.Program/EnumA
    L_001e: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_0023: nop 
    L_0024: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0025: box ConsoleApplication2.Program/EnumA
    L_002a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_002f: nop 
    L_0030: ldc.i4.4 
    L_0031: box ConsoleApplication2.Program/EnumA
    L_0036: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    L_003b: nop 
    L_003c: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
    L_0041: nop
```

That is, the loading of these enum values is loading the value "1" three times, and then calling `WriteLine`. So we should not be surprised that the 1st 3 calls all result in the *same* value.

I've tried a few experiments, but can't point to any particular (undocumented) behaviour you can rely on to predict which value will be printed.

Comment: I'm not so into MSIL :P, but it looks like the first few values are pointing to the same thing - ldc.i4.1. I'm wondering what the values of ldc.i4.2, ldc.i4.3 would be...

Comment: @Kees - yup, the ldc.i4.1 is saying "load the immediate constant value 1 onto the stack". That's the value of EnumA.One, but it's also the value of EnumA.Two and EnumA.Three - i.e. at this point in compilation, the enum names have disappeared completely, and we're working with the numeric values entirely.

Comment: So basically we can conclude that the "real value" is 1... but it is not possible for .Net to determine the value of string (as the documentation specified). (Edit: one -> 1)

Comment: @Kees - it's not possible for the compiled code to know which EnumA value you wrote in your source code - hence why it can't provide (as per Jon's answer) any guarantee on which string the `ToString()` method will return