# Why do enums behave this way?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I experienced some slightly odd behaviour today from the C# compiler, when fiddling with Enums.

```
enum FunWithEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four = 1,
    Five = 2,
    Six
}
```

Result:

- FunWithEnum.One = One
- FunWithEnum.Two = Two
- FunWithEnum.Three = Three
- FunWithEnum.Four = One
- FunWithEnum.Five = Two
- FunWithEnum.Six = Three

Can someone explain to me why the values are what they are once compiled ?

My initial guess has to do with being able to have aliases when using the enum. But I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: What is the slightly odd behavior that you experienced?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why (and how) does the order of an Enum influence the ToString value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592536/why-and-how-does-the-order-of-an-enum-influence-the-tostring-value)

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why the values are assigned the way they are.

Comment: @mbeckish: I don't agree it's the same question. In the one you are referring to, all values are assigned. In mine, they are not all assigned

Comment: The important part of the post I linked to was not that all values are assigned, it is what happens if multiple enumeration members are assigned the same underlying value: "If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return."

Comment: @mbeckish: But that is not an explanation for why the values are what they are, is it ? Why does Six become Three ? - I understand that it seems that it counts up from one, incrementing by one, except for those that are assigned. Atleast, that's the pattern I am seeing in my trials.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, because `Five` (the previous enum) is 2

Comment: @CodeMonkey - It's unclear what you mean by `FunWithEnum.Six = Three`, since that is the syntax for assignment, not equality.  If you are asking `Console.WriteLine(FunWithEnum.Six); // Why does this print Three?`, then one part of the answer is that this operation is undefined when multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value.  See @JamesB's answer for more insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

`the value of each successive enumerator is increased by 1.`

On this basis

```
One = 1,
Two,  // = 2
Three,  // = 3
Four = 1,
Five = 2,
Six //== 3
```

And also from [the answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592564/265419)

It's undefined what ToString will return when multiple enums have the same value

Answer (score 2):

The values I see in code provided are *never* assigned by compiler, it's a written by a coder.
So

- or  it's a bug leading to a mess (there is no much sence in having different enum members with the *same* associated numbers)
- or it is a code that deals with some old/legacy system, where the developer has to introduce some new values (for commodity of development or for 1000 other reasons) but remaining backcompatible with the system itself. So this is kind of workarround to extend functionality of some very old code that could not be touched.